# Set timeout for Firebase HTTPS Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

As per the documentation you can specify the timeout for a function like so:

```js
const runtimeOpts = {
  timeoutSeconds: 300,
  memory: '1GB'
}

exports.myStorageFunction = functions
  .runWith(runtimeOpts)
  .storage
  .object()
  .onFinalize((object) = > {
    // do some complicated things that take a lot of memory and time
  });
```

However, the following code fails to deploy, with error `TypeError: functions.https.runWith is not a function`:

```js
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.hello = functions.runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 540 }).https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello");
});
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the **entire** code sample that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson Which part do you mean is not complete? The first block is just from the docs for reference. My code in the second block is complete except for `const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
admin.initializeApp();
`

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  Could you edit the question to show the entire code?

Comment: Ah, sure no probelm. Have added now.

Comment: What version of the firebase-functions module are you using?

Comment: I'm using `"firebase-functions": "^3.3.0"`. I just tried deploying again and it deployed successfully. I honestly have not changed the code at all, I don't know why it was failing before, nothing has changed. I tried to deploy 3 times before and it failed with the same `TypeError: functions.https.runWith is not a function` every time. Sorry to have wasted your time.